# android: Cannot resolve symbol 'ObjectSerializer'

Tags: java, android, serialization

Android Studio has highlighted 'ObjectSerializer' red and gives the error *Cannot* *resolve* *symbol* *'ObjectSerializer'*.

I've implemented *Serializable*:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {
```

I've also checked to see *java.io.Serializable* is imported:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
```

I don't know what else could be the problem.
Code I'm trying to implement:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor sPEditor = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
sPEditor.putStringSet(cbCategoriesStates, ObjectSerializer.serialize(cbCategoriesStates));
```

Comment: Did you initialize `ObjectSerializer`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no class available as **ObjectSerializer** by default, you need to create a new class file named **ObjectSerializer.java**, you can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/sudar/android-samples/blob/master/TaskManager/src/com/sudarmuthu/android/taskmanager/util/ObjectSerializer.java) and add it to your project and then you can use the methods **serialize** or **deserialize** by importing it.